# I can't change my desktop background-image for my macbook air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop

I'm trying to change the background-image from my *MacBook Air* background, but it won't change it. I try to click on the image I want from my pictures and it makes it seem like it worked but then it hasn't changed. I tried restarting my computer but it still does not do anything. I also tried changing to one of the defaults apple has but it won't change to one of those either.

Comment: See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62194/119271

Answer (score 1):

Might be corrupted desktop preferences...

Make following steps:

- Open the Finder
- From the Finder Menu Bar click *Go > Go to Folder*
- Paste the following in this field:
  `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Click **Go** then move the `com.apple.finder.plist` file to the trash.

Restart your MacBook Air, then select a desktop background photo from *System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Desktop* and then it should work.